# Thunderbird Mail - Display only unread mail

Tags: email, thunderbird

I've begun using Thunderbird Mail and I like it. One thing I can't figure out is how to set it to, by default, only display unread mail. I can go into a folder and click the button to display unread but, when I return to this folder later, it displays all of my unread. How do I get it to always display only my unread mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the 'Quick Filter' toolbar is turned on, and select 'Unread' to show unread messages. Then also select the 'drawing pin' icon: this maintains the quick filter settings even when you change folder.
[image: Pin the 'unread' setting]

This will mean you see only unread messages in any folder you view. (If you were asking about how to see unread messages only in a particular folder, there is not a Thunderbird setting which does this.)